# Como colocar uma variável no meio da rota no angular

Tags: angular, front-end, angular-routes

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um front-end que irá se conectar com varias API's iguais, porem com bancos distintos( O Cliente tem a API instalada, mas esse front é para acesso dos colaboradores, e por questão de diminuição de manutenção atualizando em todos clientes vamos hospedar o front em um único local e fazer o controle de onde acessar), porem para saber qual API acessar gostaria de fazer ele pegar pela rota, mas como a ideia é hospedar em uma única URL gostaria de colocar o nome da empresa responsável pela API que vou acessar. Por Exemplo

> www.minhaempresa.com/{VariavelComNomeDoCliente}/{rotas normais do angular}

ai com a VariavelComNomeDoCliente faria um controle de URL para encontrar a API certa.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia definir uma variável global por exemplo quem sabe na app.js

```
var enderecos = {
    cliente1: 'www.minhaempresa.com/nomeCLiente1/',
    cliente2: 'www.minhaempresa.com/nomeCLiente2/',
}
```

ai na hora de chamar poderia fazer

```
enderecos.cliente1 + 'rota-normal'
```